# How to extract list elements into multiple tibble columns in r?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tibble

I have a very large data set in tibble form. I'd like to summarize the data using some functions which return lists. I'm interested in several components of the list, and I'd like to return each of the components I need into new tibble columns.

Here's an example

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

# Create a data set of 1,000 random values in 100 subgroups with sample size 10
contrived_data <- tibble(subgroup = rep(1:100, each = 10),
                         value    = rnorm(1000, mean = 5, sd = 1))


# Run the KS test vs. normal distribution on each sample of size 10. Return the KS statistic and p-value
# into new tibble columns
contrived_data %>% group_by(subgroup) %>%
  summarize(avg     = mean(value),
            std_dev = sd(value),
            ks_stat = ks.test(value, "pnorm", mean = 5, sd = 1)$statistic,
            ks_pval = ks.test(value, "pnorm", mean = 5, sd = 1)$p.value)
```

Running it this way gets the results I want, but not very efficiently. Calling the `ks.test` function twice means the execution time is (almost) doubled. It seems there must be a more efficient way to extract these two list components with a single function call, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can define the function and use map from purrr:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

func = function(DA){
kstest = ks.test(DA$value, "pnorm", mean = 5, sd = 1)
data.frame(
subgroup = unique(DA$subgroup),
avg=mean(DA$value),
std_dev = sd(DA$value),
ks_stat = kstest$statistic,
ks_pval = kstest$p.value)
}

contrived_data %>% 
split(.$subgroup) %>%
map_dfr(func)
```

Answer (score 3):

The test can be run once and wrapped in a `list` and then use `map` (from `purrr`) to extract the values

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
contrived_data %>% 
      group_by(subgroup) %>%
      summarize(avg     = mean(value),
                std_dev = sd(value), 
            test = list(ks.test(value, "pnorm", mean = 5, sd = 1))) %>%
      mutate(out = map(test, ~  tibble(ks_stat = .x$statistic,
                      ks_pval = .x$p.value))) %>%
      unnest_wider(c(out)) %>%
      select(-test)
# A tibble: 100 x 5
#   subgroup   avg std_dev ks_stat ks_pval
#      <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1        1  4.52   0.675   0.375  0.0907
# 2        2  5.17   1.02    0.342  0.152 
# 3        3  5.02   0.909   0.141  0.972 
# 4        4  5.08   0.846   0.313  0.227 
# 5        5  4.82   0.819   0.225  0.614 
# 6        6  5.07   0.866   0.159  0.928 
# 7        7  4.94   0.914   0.145  0.966 
# 8        8  5.52   1.01    0.290  0.306 
# 9        9  5.17   0.787   0.258  0.443 
#10       10  4.61   1.15    0.476  0.0132
# … with 90 more rows
```

---

Another option is to `tidy` the output (with `broom`) and extract all the components at once

```
library(broom)
contrived_data %>% 
       group_by(subgroup) %>%
       summarize(avg     = mean(value),
                 std_dev = sd(value), 
                 out = list(tidy(ks.test(value, "pnorm", mean = 5, sd = 1)))) %>%
       unnest_wider(c(out))
```

Comment: FYI: `map()` requires the `purrr` package.

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` solution using the `rowwise` command which performs the same task as `map` does.

```
contrived_data %>%
      group_by(subgroup) %>%
      summarise(
        avg = mean(value),
        std_dev = sd(value),
        ks_test = list(ks.test(value,"pnorm",mean=5,sd=1))
      ) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(
        ks_stat = ks_test$statistic,
        ks_pval = ks_test$p.value
      ) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(-ks_test)

# A tibble: 100 x 5
#   subgroup   avg std_dev ks_stat ks_pval
#      <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1        1  5.10   1.24    0.186  0.819 
# 2        2  4.86   0.805   0.231  0.584 
# 3        3  5.24   0.729   0.258  0.445 
# 4        4  5.16   0.642   0.307  0.247 
# 5        5  4.63   0.752   0.393  0.0664

# Benchmark using rbenchmark:
#      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#2   nested         1000   10.58    1.000     10.58        0         NA        NA
#1 original         1000   16.75    1.583     16.73        0         NA        NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use group_modify

```
library(tidyverse)

contrived_data %>% 
  group_by(subgroup) %>% 
  group_modify(~{
      ks <- ks.test(.$value, "pnorm", mean = 5, sd = 1)
      tibble(
        avg = mean(.$value), 
        std_dev = sd(.$value),
        ks_stat = ks$statistic,
        ks_pval = ks$p.value) 
  })
```

Or with data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(contrived_data)

contrived_data[, {
  ks <- ks.test(value, "pnorm", mean = 5, sd = 1)
  .(avg = mean(value), 
    std_dev = sd(value),
    ks_stat = ks$statistic,
    ks_pval = ks$p.value) 
}, by = subgroup]
```